# Viewmodel with 100 properties

Tags: wpf

Question related to WPF MVVM: I have a customer table with 100 fields. In my model I used 100 properties. Can I also create 100 properties in my view model to bind it to my page view?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Whether it's a good idea to display all 100 properties simultaneously in a view is a another question, but there is nothing stopping you from defining 100 properties in a single view model class and bind to them all from the view if you want to.